# Accessing a specific data from json

Tags: javascript, json

Here the Json file

```
 "data" : [
        {
            "mer" : "a",
            "AName" : "Am",
            "numProducts" : "69",
            "p" : "1.21",
            "color" : "#0b4977"
        },
        {
            "mer" : "b",
            "AName" : "Ma",
            "numProducts" : "42",
            "p" : "1.0",
            "color" :"#1d94dd"
        },

        {
            "mer" : "c",
            "AName" : "An",
            "numProducts" : "91",
            "p" : "1.01",
            "color" :"#09213a"
        },

        {
            "mer" : "d",
            "AName" : "A1",
            "numProducts" : "91",
            "p" : "1.01",
            "color" :"#ffcc00"
        },

        {
            "mer" : "egg",
            "AName" : "B2",
            "numProducts" : "91",
            "p" : "1.01",
            "color" :"#fcee21"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here If need to access the last 'mer' value, I would do it like data[4].mer, But I want to access the Particular value from the json file if it Matches a certain condition from the same data array.

For Example Here I have the value of "egg" for the last 'mer', Now I want to access particular color value of that. ( #fcee21) Do I have any way to do that dynamically?

Comment: Why not `data[4].color`? If you're asking how to find the color of any data where mer is "egg" or some other value, you could loop through like `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].mer == "egg") { var color = data[i].color; // do something with the color } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (data[4].mer == "egg") {
    var color = data[4].color;
}
```

What would be easier is to loop through the array testing the values of each index rather than comparing a specific index with a hard-coded if statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].mer == "egg") {
        var color = data[i].color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate object which stores your data with keys as mer and then use function getColor which returns you value based on the key provided.

```
    var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      temp[data[i].mer]  = data[i];
    };

    function getColor(key){
      return temp[key].color;

    }
```

Then you can use getColor like following.

```
    var eggColor = getColor('egg');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a somewhat complicated but pretty nicely-done solution, see [JSONiq](http://www.jsoniq.org/), which allows nice and easy manipulation and extraction of JSON formatted data.

Otherwise, for something with less overhead and hair-pulling to get it to work, consider either one of these:

- [JSONPath](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/),
- [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/) <sup>*(note: I have a preference for this one)*</sup>,
- [JSPath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath),
- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)'s [json.query](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/json/query.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use llike this:

```
    var color = '';
    if (data[4].mer == "egg") {
        color = data[4].color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you need to find the match before you get the color? Then

```
//this will work on modern browsers - for IE8 and below, use a shim, for example
//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

//data is your json object
var matchedObj = data.reduce( function( obj, current ){
                   if( "egg" === current.mer ){
                     obj = current;
                   }
                   return obj;
                 }, {});

console.log( matchedObj.color ); //either a string or undefined
```